# Problem related to indefinite integral in definite integration

Tags: definite-integrals

I tried to use binomial expansion for this problem, but it was in vain..I need the right approach. Can anyone guide me with the right idea?

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\,dx}{e^{x+1}+e^{3-x}}$$

Comment: Hint: Try the substitution $t = x-1$, and take $e^2$ common in the denominator.

Comment: Make the most obvious substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\,dx}{e^{x+1}+e^{3-x}} & = \int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^x}{e^{2x+1}+e^{3}} \, dx
\end{align*}
Let $e^{x}=t$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^x}{e^{2x+1}+e^{3}} \, dx &= \frac{1}{e}\int_e^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2+e^{2}} \, dx
\end{align*}
Now use $\arctan$ etc..